# Monitoring ports with netcat on a remote server and Zenoss

Tags: ssh, bash, zenoss

I'm pretty new to using Zenoss, so excuse if this is something simple.

I have a bash one-liner that checks a bunch of services are running on certain ports:

```
for i in {80,443,5009,5010,5020,5030,5040,5050,5060,5065,5066,5070,5080,5098}; do nc -vz localhost $i; done
```

Is there any way I can tell Zenoss to run this on the remote server over SSH and create an alert if one fails?

I have created a template against the device and added that template to zDeviceTemplates, but I'm not sure where to go from there for it to actually work.

Thank you.